# SFTP upload/download files to or from Onedrive for business using SS2.0

Tags: netsuite, onedrive, suitescript2.0

Does anyone know if it is possible yet to directly upload or download files from onedrive using SuiteScript SS2.0 without any 3rd party apps?

Answer (score 0):

If OneDrive has a REST API, you can leverage that.

Answer (score 0):

This is how we download remote files. Of course this is all dependent on the file type. To 'upload' I would hope the destination provided an API for this

```
    var resp = https.get({
        url: 'link to some file (img, txt, csv)'
    });

    var f = file.create({
        name: 'myRemoteFile.csv',
        folder: 1234565,
        fileType: file.Type.CSV,
        contents: resp.body
    });

    var id = f.save();
```